# Why is a Torus # Mobius strip $\cong$ Klein bottle # Mobius strip?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For simplicity, $T =$ torus, $M =$ Mobius strip, $K =$ Klein bottle, and $P = \Bbb RP^2$.

I would like to know why $T \# M \cong K \# M$. I know that $K = P \# P$.

The solution says $T \# M \cong T \# P$ and $K \# M \cong K \# P$, but I don't understand these homeomorphisms either.

Comment: How do you define $T\# M $? By butting a small ball in $T$ and then glue along the boundary of $M$?

Comment: @JohnMa I think so

Comment: If you delete a small ball in $P$, you get $M$. So "deleting a small ball in $X$, deleting a small ball in $P$, and gluing along the boundary" is the same as "deleting a small ball in $X$, and gluing along the boundary of $M$". That is, X#P = X#M for any connected surface X.

Comment: why not to read (and understand)  the *Conway's ZIP-proof*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in general true that for any surface $S$,

$$S \#  M \cong S \# P.$$

The reason is that $P$ can be formed by gluing a two cell to $M$ along the boundary of the two cell and that of $M$.

So when you construct $S\# P$, you cut away a two cell $D_S$ on $S$, a two cell $D_P$ on $P$, and then glue along the boundary. Now when you cut away $D_P$ on $P$, you got a Mobius strip $M$, then you glue the boundary of this $M$ to the boundary of the $D_S$ in $S$, which is exactly how you form $S \#  M$.

Comment: Your # is not a connected sum, because a connected sum deletes a ball in the interior of both manifolds and glues. S # M has boundary. What do you mean by #?

Comment: @MikeMiller : Please see the comment. I agree that this is just not the established notation.

Comment: I misread your comment, sorry.